# ORA - 00935: missing expression

Tags: oracle, select, sql, ora-00936

This is my code:

```
select max(vhis_data.C0432_SAMPL_VALUE1_R), vhis_data.C0401_aid
from vhis_data, T0401_accounts
where vhis_data.C0401_aid = T0401_accounts.C0401_aid
and (
vhis_data.c0401_aid between 1179 and 1291 or
vhis_data.c0401_aid between 1382 and 1402 or
vhis_data.c0401_aid between 1462 and 1620 or

# and so on until...

vhis_data.c0401_aid between 5450 and 5485 or
vhis_data.c0401_aid between 5503 and 5495 or
)
```

(these numbers represent various points in the system)

The program displayed an error:

```
 vhis_data.c0401_aid between 1179 and 1291 or
*
 ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

What I've noticed is that the first part of the error references the **first line** in the 
`and ( ... )` part of my code.
I have also noticed that there is an extra `or` on the **last line** of my code. I can take it out, but is this extra `or` the *only* reason that the whole `and (...)` part does not work? Or is there another reason that my code is not working?

**(I guess a sub-question of mine, then, is, if there is a missing expression, where does the code stop executing properly?)**

For example, here, the missing expression is potentially the last line (because it is expecting something after the "or"). However, the code does not even go through the first line of the `and (...)` part of the code.

I have combed the net for explanations dealing with the error *ORA-00936: missing expression* but have not found anything relevant enough to help me in this particular situation.

I welcome any criticism or advice you may have, and thank you so much in advance for any contributions that you give me!

Comment: The query is parsed as a whole. When you say _the code does not even go through the first line of the and (...) part of the code_, that doesn't really make sense. Now, the line # reported by the error may not always point you to the exact right place, unfortunately

Comment: Oracle has some rather vague error messages.  This is one of those.  A good way to determine the cause is to take baby steps.  Write a skelton query and run it.  Then add a little bit and run it again.  If you get an error the second time, you'll know that it was caused by the bit you just added.

Answer (score 1):

you should not end the whole thing with an or

```
 5495 or
)
```

this makes the entire parenthetical phrase invalid - everything in the ()... so thats why the line number is flagged up top.

Answer (score 1):

> Could this extra or be the only reason that the whole and (...) part does not work?

It's the reason the *whole query* does not work.

A SQL query does not "execute" in order like a string of commands.  The entire query is compiled, a plan built, and the plan executed.  For that reason any syntax errors are often shown to point to lines that do not have the actual error.

So the "code" does not "execute" *at all*.  The compilation fails, so there's nothing to execute.

Comment: But why, in the error, does it reference only the first line of the "and (...)" part of the code? Why not the last line, where the error truly lies (because I mistakenly added an "or" there)?

Comment: Like I said in my other comment, you can't really rely on the line # to point you to the exact problem. Your error is at the bottom of that `and` expression, and therefore it's pointing you at the `and`.

Comment: Because from a SQL point of view everything inside the AND is _one statement_. Just because you have line breaks doesn't mean each condition is compiled separately.  The error then shows you that statement, and since you have line breaks it shows you the first line.  If you did not have line breaks it would probably show you more.